# ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' when adding a primary key

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

I already have a table with some data in it. And now I want to add a new column "id" and make it a primary key. I'm using MySQL Workbench. So, I'm just adding a new key and then setting it as PK and NN. But for some reason, this apparently simple and straightforward operation doesn't work. I get:

> ERROR 1062: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have a field set as primary key in that table.
I guess you would have to disable that field as PK and add the new `id`-column in the same statement.

Comment: I don't have any other primary key.

Comment: @VisanCosmin Could you please add your SQL-Statement and column definitions of your table to your question?

Comment: I'm using mySql Workbench. I'm just selecting PK and NN and click apply.

(I cannot insert a picture, because I don't have reputation at least 10.)

Comment: All I can think of is backing up the table data and recreate the table. Maybe this will help.